# Firefox issue with Javascript click event on input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, primefaces

I'm using some Jquery code to modify the style class of a label that is related with the input being clicked. So to do that, I'm using the `ui-state-active` class added by primefaces, something like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked"); //Just to have a reference of the component being clicked
    if ($("div:has(.clicked) + div").hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
        addSelected(compo); //Add class to the label related with the input
    } else {
        rmvSelected(compo); //Remove class to the label related with the input
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});

$("input[type='radio']").click( function() {
    //same
});
```

I know the code is kind of complex, but I had to do it like this because of the way primefaces renders it. The thing is, most of browsers like chrome, IE10, and even firefox just with the `input[type='radio']` work like this: once the input is clicked, the class `ui-state-active` is added, and then the javascript click event is called, so my code works perfectly this way. But is happening to me that, just in firefox and just with the `input[type='checkbox']` is working the other way around, i.e. is calling the click event first and then is adding the class `ui-state-active`, which makes my code fail. Is this a firefox bug? or a problem with my code? how can I solve it? Thanks.

PD: Tested with latest firefox version: 30.0

Comment: Can you setup as jsFiddle and replicate the issue?

Comment: Which checkbox are you using `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` or `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` ?

Comment: `p:selectManyCheckbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm temporarily solving it using `if ($.browser.mozilla) {` to add the needed behavior when the browser is firefox. Although I'm still looking for a more stylish solution.